# Showing that each path connected component of a locally path-connected space is open

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If $X$ was a locally path-connected space. How would you show that for each $x_0 \in X$, the set of points $V$, path connected to $x_0$, is open?

Comment: This proposition is a special case of the more general theorem (from Munkres' Topology; Theorem 25.4 of Section 25): A space $X$ is locally path connected if and only if for every open set $U$ of $X$, each path connected component of $U$ is open in $X$. $X$ itself is open, so each of its path connected components is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in V$ and $W$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Without loss of generality, you can suppose $W$ path-connected, because $X$ is locally path-connected.

Let $y \in W$. Then there is a path $\gamma_1$ from $x_0$ to $x$ (since $x \in V$), and a path $\gamma_2$ from $x$ to $y$ (since $W$ is path-connected). Then $\gamma:= \gamma_2\gamma_1$ is a path from $x_0$ to $y$, so $y \in V$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only bit I can't see is why we can assume WLOG that $W$ is path-connected?

Comment: @user53076: In fact, you choose $W$, and because $X$ is locally path-connected, you can suppose $W$ path-connected.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand why you're allowed to suppose that?

Comment: By definition of locally path-connectedness, there exists an open path-connected neighborhood of $x$; then just call it $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Show that $x\sim y$ iff $x$ can be joined to $y$ via a path is an equivalence relation. Then for a point $x\in V$ the set of points path-connented to $x$ equals $V$. Now it is easy to find a neighborhood about $x$ that must lie in $V$.